# Call function from another React component

Tags: reactjs

My first component is as follow:

```
const hellos = ['Hola', 'Salut', 'Hallo', 'Ciao', 'Ahoj', 'Annyeong-haseyo', 'Aloha', 'Howdy', 'Ni Hao', 'Konnichiwa']

export class Welcome extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            errors: []
        };
    }

    sayHello = function() {
        return hellos[Math.floor((Math.random()*hellos.length))];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Welcome">

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call `sayHello()` from another component. All answers I've seen so far talk about parent and child relationships but in this case the two components don't have any relationship. I thought of something like this but it doesn't do the job:

```
import { Welcome } from './Welcome'

export const Life = () => (
    <div className="Life">
      <p>{ Welcome.sayHello() }</p>
    </div>
)
```

I would like to get a random element of the `hellos` array printed in Life.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right design pattern...

Comment: I forgot a line with the method call.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen in the Life component? Should it show the Welcome component at all? Because your current code will not.

Comment: @ocram Well, the reason why it's not working is because `sayHello` is a *method* of an instance, not a static function. You would have to create an instance of `Welcome` via creating a `Welcome` element and using refs or making it static. Anyways, this seems like the wrong decision.

Comment: It has to be parent child relationship. React works on props and states architecture. If you want to use sayHello in other component, then you will have to pass sayHello as prop to the other component from this component.

Comment: I added what I expect to get now. @nem035

Comment: It's worth backing up and considering what your React components should be used for. They are presentational elements meant to receive prop values from parents as part of an overall purpose to generate render output. They aren't meant to be used like library classes. You can instead put your sayHello() in a reusable named function like user2340824 recommended. This makes particular sense since your sayHello() function doesn't rely on component state at all.

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of ways you could achieve this:

You can do this by creating the sayHello function and using it simply as a named-function.

**hello.js**

```
const hellos = ['Hola', 'Salut', 'Hallo', 'Ciao', 'Ahoj', 'Annyeong-haseyo', 'Aloha', 'Howdy', 'Ni Hao', 'Konnichiwa'];

const sayHello = function() {
    return hellos[Math.floor((Math.random()*hellos.length))];
};

export { sayHello };
```

Then you can import into which ever component you wish to share the functionality:

```
import { sayHello } from './hello';

class CompA extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <span>{sayHello()}</span>;
    }
}

class CompB extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <span>{sayHello()}</span>;
    }
}

render(<span>
        <CompA />
        <CompB />
    </span>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Created a https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkgrwrMGePG4ixI0EKd

Another way, is to simply define your sayHello Function as static.

```
static sayHello() {
    return hellos[Math.floor((Math.random()*hellos.length))];
}
```

Comment: or you can use a ref for a component and call a method on it.